# Access is Denied in IE10 when using CORS to call a local URL

Tags: internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, cors

I have enabled cors on my server and i'm using this [website](http://client.cors-api.appspot.com/client) to test if cors was enabled successfully on my server.

When i use chrome the call to `http://myserver/iisstart.htm` it succeeds but when i use IE i get an exception SCRIPT 5: Access is Denied on the line `xhr.open(method, url, true);`

The error is happening on the open method so it is not about the server configuration. 
if i call `http://myserver.com/iisstart.htm` i don't have this error anymore, but of course the call won't work because i'm not on .com

So why IE doesn't allow opening the XMLHttpRequest when the url refers to a local address?

Answer (score 2):

Sites on your local network are run with Enhanced Protection Mode enabled by default. This prevents your local network from accessing potentially unsafe pages from another zone (i.e. the Internet zone).

You have a couple options to solve this:
1) Ensure you're only making requests to local resources.
2) Disable EPM on your Local intranet zone (Internet Options -> Security -> Local Intranet -> Uncheck 'Enable Protected Mode'). This is potentially unsafe.
3) Add your server and the remote resources to your Trusted Sites list.

Good luck, hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Grant, I did what you recommended but no luck. But you gave me an idea when you talked about multiple zones interacting with each other. So i saved the web page on my Desktop and opened html file and now i can make the CORS call.

Comment: The security zone issues go a step further than just EPM, if you use Native XMLHTTP in IE. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537505(VS.85).aspx#xdomain